# Did I just delete 2 Months of Work?

Tags: github-desktop

I was about to back up my local work to github today (1,100 commits). Not sure what I did but all of a sudden it says no commits, and all my Xcode files are now red. It seems to have synced my local files with the github files deleting everything locally. Is there anything I can do!?!?

It's 2 months of work :(

## Update:

`git reflog` shows the following:

```
8ad5e45 HEAD@{18}: commit: UI/UX Improvements for Sign Up Process
5c2d47f HEAD@{19}: checkout: moving from myBranch to master
5c2d47f HEAD@{20}: checkout: moving from master to myBranch
5c2d47f HEAD@{21}: checkout: moving from myBranch to master
5c2d47f HEAD@{22}: checkout: moving from master to myBranch
```

`UI/UX Improvements for Sign Up Process` was a pull request I submitted back in November. So I think what cleared my local files was accidentally tapping the "branch tab on my github desktop app and switching it. I switched back to see if it would undo it but nothing changed.

[image]

Comment: Commit daily! That's the point of Github! Make it automated! Are you sure the files are nowhere to be found on your desktop? Check the `Event Viewer` and see if there's any trace of you removing the files. Check everywhere. EVERYWHERE.

Comment: What does `git reflog` show?

Comment: Hi @DavidSchwartz I just updated my answer with the result.

Comment: @AaronLayfield Where's the ```Event Viewer```?

Comment: @AaronLayfield source control should not serve as the (main) backup method. Committing itself does not help you (OP states they lost 1100 commits), and pushing to a remote (e.g. GitHub) is not the same as doing a backup, either.

Comment: @Stijn It can be if you're working from your own fork/repository. Of course its not the main backup method, but its better then losing 1,100 commits. Edit: Realised I said 'That's the point of Github', but I can't edit that comment anymore and that's definitely not what I meant, sorry.

Comment: What happens when you do stuff like `git log HEAD@{1}`?

Comment: Hey David, it returns a push done back in November.

Comment: :( That's not looking good.

Comment: Yeah :/ Honestly I've learned my lesson. I'm just gonna take the L and try to redo as much as I can. I'm sure it'll end up better than before.